# Best way to sum two generic values in Swift

Tags: swift

I want to write a function that takes two values of the same type and returns the sum.
My current approach is this:

```
protocol Summable {
    static func +(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
}

extension Int: Summable {}
extension String: Summable {}
extension Double: Summable {}

func sum<T: Summable>(_ obj1: T, with obj2: T) -> T {
        return obj1 + obj2
}


print(sum(5, with: 4)) // 9
print(sum(5.5, with: 4.3)) // 9.8
print(sum("5", with: "4")) // 54
```

Is this the best that can be done or it can be improved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to make sure your type can be summed all you need to do is to constrain your generic type to [additivearithmetic](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/additivearithmetic)

If you need to support Strings, make it conform to AdditiveArithmetic but you will need to implement subtraction as well:

```
extension String: AdditiveArithmetic {
    public static func -= (lhs: inout String, rhs: String) {
            var set = Set(rhs)
        lhs.removeAll{ !set.insert($0).inserted }
    }
    public static func - (lhs: String, rhs: String) -> String {
        var set = Set(rhs)
        return lhs.filter{set.insert($0).inserted}
    }
    public static var zero: String { "" }
}
```

---

```
func sum<T: AdditiveArithmetic>(_ lhs: T, with rhs: T) -> T {
    lhs + rhs
}
```

---

```
func subtract<T: AdditiveArithmetic>(_ lhs: T, from rhs: T) -> T {
    rhs - lhs
}
```

---

```
print(sum(5, with: 4)) // 9
print(sum(5.5, with: 4.3)) // 9.8
print(sum("5", with: "4")) // 54
print(subtract("5", from: "12345"))  // "1234\n"
"12345" - "5" // "1234"
```